# a range of various ...?

Tags: usage, vocabulary

***a range of*** and ***various*** are somewhat overlapped words in meaning, right? Do you use it to emphasize ***many different*** things?

> Finance ministers were ordered to develop plans for "deploying ***a
> range of various*** options" for the fund to help bring down borrowing
> costs. - The New York Times

Comment: If you want to be emphatic, it's ***a wide / broad / extensive range***. But you can't *directly* intensify adjectival ***various*** like that, so you'd have to switch to the noun form with ***a wide variety***. In and of themselves, neither of ***a range of*** nor ***various***  implies greater or less diversity than the other. Imho, ***a range of various options*** is substandard writing.

Comment: I agree with FumbleFingers. "... a range of various options" is redundant and sounds kind of dumb.

Comment: It's very common in English writing to use multiple words for emphasis even when the pedants might complain about redundancy or pleonasm. "A range" means they are setting out several things, "various" emphasises that they are different - you could have a range of similar things (differing only slightly and in a regular way, like some spoons). It emphasises that multiple things are being proposed, and they are all different in nature (spoons, forks, knives, chopsticks...); two separate points.